# Can I create one command for quoting?

Tags: macros, punctuation, quoting

I would like to get this result:

[image]

I currently use this piece to get the result:

```
\glqq{\textit{Analysis II}}\grqq{}
```

Can I create a single command like the following to get the desired result?

```
\quoteitalic{Analysis II}
```

Comment: `\glqq` should be also used as `\glqq{}` or `\glqq\textit{#1}` because it doesn't have a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with quotes the [csquotes](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) package is most convenient. Then you won’t have to use `\glqq` and `\grqq` at all. The basic usage would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\enquote{\textit{Analysis II}}
\end{document}
```

Of course you can make your italic quotes into a custom macro with

```
\newcommand\iquote[1]{\enquote{\textit{#1}}}
```

and use it as `\iquote{Analysis II}`. Personally I like to use unicode quotation marks. To enable them use `\MakeAutoQuote{“}{”}` and apply them as `“\textit{Analysis II}”`. This way no custom macro is necessary. (When using *PdfLaTeX*, add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.)

`csquotes` allows you to have language-specific quotes without changing the quotation itself. Furthermore you can nest those quotes, e.g.

```
Professor: “Use the book “\textit{Analysis II}” as a reference.”
```

would show as

[image: example for nested quotes with csquotes]

when using the default language setting.

Comment: Another advantage is that you cannot forget only one quote.

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
 \newcommand{\quoteitalic}[1]{\glqq\textit{#1}\grqq}
```

[image]

### Notes:

- As Qrrbrbirlbel commented, `\glqq` does not have a parameter, so I have corrected the definition of the `\quoteitalic` macro.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newcommand{\quoteitalic}[1]{\glqq\textit{#1}\grqq}

\begin{document}
\glqq{\textit{Analysis II}}\grqq{}

\quoteitalic{Analysis II}
\end{document}
```